# Get session events from Hazelcast session repository?

Tags: spring, session, events, hazelcast

I'm not getting session closed or expired events when using embedded Hazelcast session repository in Spring boot application. I do get session creation events. I have a very short timeout for the sessions (30s). I have verified that the session gets expired after 30s by getting "unauthorized" reply from the server. How do you receive session expiration/destruction events?

This is my session configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableHazelcastHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 30)
public class SessionConfiguration{

    @Bean
    @SpringSessionHazelcastInstance
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setClusterName("spring-session-cluster");

        // Add this attribute to be able to query sessions by their PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE's
        AttributeConfig attributeConfig = new AttributeConfig()
                .setName(Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE)
                .setExtractorClassName(Hazelcast4PrincipalNameExtractor.class.getName());

        // Configure the sessions map
        config.getMapConfig(Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.DEFAULT_SESSION_MAP_NAME)
                .addAttributeConfig(attributeConfig).addIndexConfig(
                new IndexConfig(IndexType.HASH, Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE));

        // Use use custom serializer to de/serialize sessions faster. This is optional.
        SerializerConfig serializerConfig = new SerializerConfig();
        serializerConfig.setImplementation(new HazelcastSessionSerializer()).setTypeClass(MapSession.class);
        config.getSerializationConfig().addSerializerConfig(serializerConfig);

        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SessionRepositoryCustomizer<Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository> customize() {
        return (sessionRepository) -> {
            sessionRepository.setFlushMode(FlushMode.IMMEDIATE);
            sessionRepository.setSaveMode(SaveMode.ALWAYS);
            sessionRepository.setSessionMapName(Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.DEFAULT_SESSION_MAP_NAME);
            sessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(30); //this is extra; tried with and without
        };
    }
}
```

And this is my listener:

```
@Component
public class SessionListener {
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionListener.class);

    @EventListener
    public void sessionCreated(SessionCreatedEvent event) {
        log.info("SESSION:CREATE:ID="+event.getSessionId()); //only this gets called but none of the others
    }
    
    @EventListener
    public void sessionDeleted(SessionDeletedEvent event) {
        log.info("SESSION:DELETE:ID="+event.getSessionId());
    }
    
    @EventListener
    public void sessionDestroyed(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {
        log.info("SESSION:DESTROY:ID="+event.getId());
    }
    
    @EventListener
    public void sessionExpired(SessionExpiredEvent event) {
        log.info("SESSION:EXPIRE:ID="+event.getSessionId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer (I don't know exactly why it works):

If you add a session map listener to HazelcastInstance (in the creating bean) you suddenly start receiving SessionExpiredEvents.

So replace lines:

```
config.getMapConfig(Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.DEFAULT_SESSION_MAP_NAME)
            .addAttributeConfig(attributeConfig).addIndexConfig(
            new IndexConfig(IndexType.HASH, Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE));
```

with (set maximum idle seconds to the session map configuration):

```
config.getMapConfig(Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.DEFAULT_SESSION_MAP_NAME)
            .addAttributeConfig(attributeConfig).addIndexConfig(
            new IndexConfig(IndexType.HASH, Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE))
            .setMaxIdleSeconds(tout);
```

and

```
return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

with (add session entry listener to the session map)

```
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
IMap<Object, Object> map = instance.getMap( Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.DEFAULT_SESSION_MAP_NAME );
map.addEntryListener( new HazelcastSessionEntryListener(), true );
return instance;
```

where HazelcastSessionEntryListener can be defined like this:

```
@Component
public class HazelcastSessionEntryListener implements EntryListener<Object, Object>
{
    public HazelcastSessionEntryListener(){}

    @Override
    public void entryAdded(EntryEvent<Object, Object> event){}

    @Override
    public void entryUpdated(EntryEvent<Object, Object> event){}

    @Override
    public void entryRemoved(EntryEvent<Object, Object> event){}

    @Override
    public void entryEvicted(EntryEvent<Object, Object> event){}

    @Override
    public void entryExpired(EntryEvent<Object, Object> event){}

    @Override
    public void mapCleared(MapEvent event){}

    @Override
    public void mapEvicted(MapEvent event){}
}
```

Funny thing is that HazelcastSessionEntryListener is just an empty implementation in my case (it doesn't do anything). Seems like buggy behaviour (but I'm not a Spring expert).